# How to disable html button if input is empty?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a modal from bootstrap to allow users to post comments on my website. Everything is okay except that the user can post a comment if the input is null. I want to disable the button if the input is null

**This is the button modal from bootstrap**

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-dark"
  data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
  id="addComment"
>
  Add a comment
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="exampleModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add a comment</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Name"
            id="name"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Comment"
            id="comment"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-light"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-dark"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          id="postButton"
          onclick="postComment()"
        >
          Comment
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### What have I tried?

1. I tried loading the Dom and then add event listener to the "add
   comment" button and watch for input changes such as:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
     var addbutton = document.getElementById("addComment");
     addbutton.addEventListener("click", () => {
       var name = document.getElementById("name");
       name.addEventListener("change", () => {
         if (name.value.length > 0) {
           document.getElementById("postButton").disabled = false;
         } else {
           document.getElementById("postButton").disabled = true;
         }
       });
     });
   });
   ```
2. I googled if there is a required field in bootstrap and even added `required` to both inputs but this didn't work.
3. I've also tried setting the button attribute `disabled` and work with above code but didn't work

I've tried more things but they didn't quite work. As I mentioned above, I need to disable the html button if the input is null. Any help is appreciated.

P.S I'm first trying on a single input then I will work on both

Comment: Where is `postComment` defined? The thing that is called when the button "`Comment`" is pressed. You should probably be checking there if the length of the input > 0.

Comment: I want to disable the button if the inputs are null not when I press the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt sets the event handler on `name` when the `click` event happens on the button and all of that is set up in a handler for `DOMContentLoaded`. This can be simplified greatly.

If you move your `script` so that it is positioned just prior to the closing `body` tag, you won't need to nest your code inside of a `DOMConentLoaded` event handler because by the time the parser reaches this point, the DOM will be loaded. Next, you just need to set up a `blur` event handler (which fires when a field loses the focus) or the `input` event (which fires every time the `value` of the field changes) that checks to see if the element has content and enables/disables the button accordingly.

Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Enable/Disable submit</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input id="one"><input id="two"><button disabled>Submit</button>

  <!-- By placing the script just before the closing
       body tag, you ensure that all the other elements
       have been parsed into memory when the script runs. -->
  <script>
    const input1 = document.querySelector("#one");  
    const input2 = document.querySelector("#two");    
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    
    // Use the same validation handler for both inputs
    input1.addEventListener("input", validate);
    input2.addEventListener("input", validate);    
    
    function validate(){
      // Check that neither input is empty
      if(input1.value === "" || input2.value === ""){
        btn.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
      } else {
        btn.removeAttribute("disabled");  
      }
    }    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is if the the first input is not null but the second is null, the user can post a comment. That means that the first input can be submitted alone but not the second

Comment: @NabilTheCoder Check out the updated answer. It's just a matter of having both inputs use the same handler and having the handler check both inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was really tired and you helped me. Just curious about using `getElementById` and `querySelector`. Which is better?

Comment: @NabilTheCoder You're welcome (don't forget to up vote and mark as the answer). There's not a lot of difference between `getElementById` and `querySelector` although technically, `getElementById` could be slightly faster due to how browsers store `id`s, but in modern applications, you wouldn't be able to notice such a small difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the input required

`<input type="text">` ===> `<input type="text" required>`

However, it think if someone changes the tag they can enter in nothing.  In that case just check for posts with a value of nothing and prevent them from being put in the db.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you have wrong here.

- You have an event listener inside an event listener

Each time `addbutton` is clicked you assign a new event listener to `name` which is redundant. You have to move `name.addEventListener` outside.

```js
let name = document.getElementById("name");

name.addEventListener("input", () => { // Also using `input` instead of `change`
    if (name.value.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById("postButton").disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("postButton").disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Notice something different here as well? Instead of using `"change"` I've used `"input"` because it makes changes in real time (when you type), while `"change"` gets triggered when you focus outside of the input.

Now when the document is loaded you have to disable the button and you will be set.

Also instead of using the old style `onLoad` event listeners you put your script after the HTML and then you can attach a `defer` to your script like this.

```
<script defer>
// Your Javascript will be executed
// after all the html has been loaded
</script>
```

```js
let name = document.getElementById("name");
let postButton = document.getElementById("postButton");
postButton.disabled = true;
name.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (name.value.length > 0) {
      postButton.disabled = false;
    } else {
      postButton.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-dark"
  data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
  id="addComment"
>
  Add a comment
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="exampleModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add a comment</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Name"
            id="name"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Comment"
            id="comment"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-light"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-dark"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          id="postButton"
          onclick="postComment()"
        >
          Comment
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try your code snippet. it will best explain my problem

Comment: Thanks man I got the idea. You got an upvote